# rails: delayed-job progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, progress

I am trying to show user a progress bar for a task running in the delayed job.
I am populating a large amount of data using delayed job in the database like this.

```
class ImportSchoolsAndDistricts < Struct.new(:import, :content)
  def perform
    total = content.size
    content.each_with_index do |record,index|
      # create records here
      import.update_attribute(:progress, (index + 1)/total*100)
    end
  end
end
```

end

`:import` is an instance of Import model with an attribute `progress`. I will use this `progress` attribute to display to the user the status of job as a percentage.

But the update of `progress` is not occurring continuously. It is updating only twice: once at the beginning and once at the end, so the values i am getting for progress are 0% and 100%.

Since i am using ruby 1.9, I cannot use progress_bar https://github.com/d4be4st/progress_job (requires Ruby 2.0.0)

Comment: Looks like your code is missing an `end`: is the `update_attribute` supposed to be happening inside the `each_with_index` block?

Comment: Do you see the output on the console or in the log showing the database actions?

Comment: @Daiku yes the update command to the `imports` table is shown only twice. Once in the beginning(update `progress` to 0) and once at the end(update `progress` to 100).

Comment: Seems someone is "helping" you by optimizing.  There's probably a way to force the db to flush it's cached actions.  Of course, what you are trying to do is actually kind of expensive.  You will be slowing down the updates, in order to show the user how fast it's running?